# User Interface on Top Rajawali Surface View

Tags: rajawali, 3d-rendering

Anyone who knows how to add User Inteface on top of Rajawali Surface View?
I check the rajawali documentation but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The following approach worked for me: Create your UI elements that you want to add to your layout, I used a `ConstraintLayout` as a container. Do not create the `SurfaceView` by xml, but instead programmatically. Create it in a way that it will overlap all other UI elements and that it uses all available space. By this, the UI elements are still visible even though technically they should be hidden by the `SurfaceView` which is in front.

Below is my code how I setup the `SurfaceView`. Note that constraintLayout is the name of the container layout that has other buttons in it as well.

```
surfaceView = new SurfaceView(getContext());
surfaceView.setFrameRate(30.0);
surfaceView.setRenderMode(ISurface.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
surfaceView.setSurfaceRenderer(YOUR_RENDERER);

surfaceView.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT));
surfaceView.setId(View.generateViewId());
constraintLayout.addView(surfaceView, 0);
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
constraintSet.connect(surfaceView.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT);
constraintSet.connect(surfaceView.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
constraintSet.connect(surfaceView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
constraintSet.connect(surfaceView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP);
constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```